# Label equations arbitrarily

Tags: equations, labels

When I have equations, as in

```
\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}
```

Can I arbitrarily assign the numbers to the equations? Instead of the usual order (1), (2), (3), ..., I'd like something like (1), (2.1), (2.2), (2.3), (3.1), (3.2), (4), ...

Comment: Is there some logic behind the numbering, or is it purely arbitrary?

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your question. They are the equations under Theorem 1, Theorem 2, and so on. Is there a convenient way to do the numbering?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, using the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) package and its `\tag` command.

A little example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b\tag{1.2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b\tag{duck}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

After reading your comment, if you want the `equation` number to inherit the `theorem` number, then you can use, for example,

```
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{equation}{mytheorem}
```

and then you don't have to tag equations manually.