# How to give a specific name to equation

Tags: equations, labels

I want to call my equation `$NS_\alpha$` in such a manner that rather than

> (1.1)

the equation shows up with

> ($NS_\alpha$)

Comment: Although I am not really sure what exactly you want to achieve, maybe this answer helps you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97295/134144

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Using `\tag{$NS_\alpha$}` should do it. For cross-reference, add something like `\label{eq-NSalph}` (I mean, no math formula in the label).